# Why BroadcastReceiver reacts 3-4 seconds after event on locked screen?

Tags: java, android, lockscreen

when the screen is unlocked, onReceive method fires instantly (in my case after incoming call), but in locked screen case it waits 4-5 seconds and then fires. What causes this delay and how do i make onReceive method fire instantly on locked screen? Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

The onReceive() method IS firing immediately. This has to do with how the Android platform is handling Intent delivery when the screen is locked vs when the device is being actively used.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I've put only a toast into onReceive() method and it was shown after ~4 seconds on lockscreen, so i guess it's not firing immediately